# How to normalize input of neural network predicting stock market [python]

Tags: python, neural-network, normalization

I am trying to implement a neural network that predicts the stock market in python. In input I have a 2d numpy array and I want to normalize the data. 
I tried with this code but I don't this this is the best choice for this type of task.

```
def normData(data):
    #data_scaled = preprocessing.scale(data)
    data = scale( data, axis=0, with_mean=True, with_std=True, copy=True )
    return data
```

Do you know any other kind of normalization process that could better fit this task and its python implementation?
Thank you

UPDATE:
 Now before the normalization I transfrom the ndarray to list, but printing

```
print data.mean(axis=0)
```

the mean is way far from 0. Its something like 4. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would use scikit-learn's standard scalar module. It allows you to pick the mean and standard deviation that you want and is very fast.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Load data and split into testing and training data

scale = StandardScaler(with_mean=0, with_std=1)
scale.fit(training_data, training_label)
new_training_data = scale.transform(training_data)
new_testing_data = scale.transform(testing_data)
```

A link to the documentation:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it gives me some warnings. I updated the question with them

Comment: my data contains 6 different features.

Comment: Two possible reasons for the mean being wrong: I believe that the data scaling is on a per-class basis. If you for some reason don't want to do this, then remove the labels from the initial fitting. Also, the scaling applied to testing data is a learned transformation with some error. It is possible that this is the source of your error. This only applies to testing data though.

Comment: what should I put on training_label? now I have y=None, because I dont get what should I put there. thank you for your precious help

Comment: Neural networks are supervised classifiers therefore they need labeled data to be trained. For your stock market example, you might use two labels i.e. increasing and decreasing prices.